# How to set a custom position size on Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

My bot uses a stopATR as the stop. But there's some issue with my position size/quantity on the `strategy.entry` line.
So I need to set a position size based on my `strategy.equity` and the distance to the ATR.
Example: If from my entry price to the ATR is $50 and my total capital is $1000 and I wanna a risk of 10% ($100) I can open a position of 2 contracts.

I calculate the difference between ATR line and entry price the following way:

```
//@version=4
//calculate difference between entry and atr
differenceLong = strategy.position_avg_price - atr_at_entry
differenceShort = atr_at_entry - strategy.position_avg_price
```

Once I get this value I need to calculate the size of my order the following way:

```
//Calculate position size
positionSize1 = (strategy.equity * risk) / differenceLong
positionSize2 = (strategy.equity * risk) / differenceShort
```

So now I have my position size as it should be.

(capital*risk%) / distance from entry to atr line

```
strategy.entry("long",   true, when = buy and time_cond, qty=positionSize1)
strategy.entry("short", false, when = sell and time_cond, qty=positionSize2)
```

And then I try to open the order, the editor saves the code with no error syntax but the bot doesn't work on the chart. (Study error) So the problem is on the `qty=positionSize` because once I delete it, it works fine. Maybe I'm using the `strategy.equity` the wrong way.

here's the whole code:

```
//CREDITS to HPotter for the orginal code. The guy trying to sell this as his own is a scammer lol. 

// Calculate start/end date and time condition
startDate  = input(timestamp("2022-06-20T00:00:00"), type = input.time)
finishDate = input(timestamp("2022-12-01T00:00:00"), type = input.time)
 
time_cond  = time >= startDate and time <= finishDate

// Inputs
src = close 
var initialCapital = strategy.equity

keyvalue = input(2.5, title = "Fequência", step = .5)
atrperiod = 15
xATR = atr(atrperiod)
nLoss = keyvalue * xATR
risk = input(1, title="Capital Risk (%)")
rr = input(1, title="Risk Reward Ratio", step = 0.5)

//Calculate atr metrics
xATRTrailingStop = 0.0
xATRTrailingStop := iff(src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src - nLoss),
   iff(src < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), src + nLoss), 
   iff(src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), src - nLoss, src + nLoss)))
 
pos = 0   
pos :=  iff(src[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 1,
   iff(src[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and src < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), -1, nz(pos[1], 0))) 
   
xcolor = pos == -1 ? color.red: pos == 1 ? color.green : color.blue

plot(xATRTrailingStop, color = xcolor, title = "Trailing Stop")
buy = crossover(src,xATRTrailingStop)
sell = crossunder(src,xATRTrailingStop)
barcolor = src > xATRTrailingStop 

plotshape(buy, title = "Buy", text = 'Buy', style = shape.labelup, location = location.belowbar, color= color.green,textcolor = color.white, transp = 0, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(sell, title = "Sell", text = 'Sell', style = shape.labeldown, color= color.red,textcolor = color.white, transp = 0, size = size.tiny)


//get the value of atr at the entry bar
var float atr_at_entry = na

is_new_long = (strategy.position_size > 0) and (strategy.position_size > strategy.position_size[1])
is_new_short = (strategy.position_size < 0) and (strategy.position_size < strategy.position_size[1])
is_new_entry = is_new_long or is_new_short

atr_at_entry := is_new_entry ? xATRTrailingStop : atr_at_entry

//calculate difference between entry and atr
differenceLong = strategy.position_avg_price - atr_at_entry
differenceShort = atr_at_entry - strategy.position_avg_price

//Calculate position size
positionSize1 = (strategy.equity * risk) / differenceLong
positionSize2 = (strategy.equity * risk) / differenceShort

//Calculate the TP price

longExitPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price + (differenceLong * rr)
shortExitPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price - (differenceShort * rr)

strategy.entry("long",   true, when = buy and time_cond)
strategy.entry("short", false, when = sell and time_cond)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id="TP", limit = longExitPrice)

        
if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit(id="TP", limit = shortExitPrice)
```

Comment: The error `quantity for entry or order must be a positive number less or equal to 1000000000.000000, passed value is -2542.44383` speaks for itself. Your `positionSize1` and `positionSize2` variables are negative, and you cannot create order with negative number of contracts. Try to plot these values. Check your calculations, or if they are correct then just use `abs(positionSize1)` and `abs(positionSize2)`

Comment: You are correct. The maths was giving me a invalid number